# What's the field size of function type member in struct?

Tags: solidity

Is it 24 bytes as the doc said,  although it's referring to the argument encoding instead of the storage layout? [Here](https://x9453.github.io/2020/01/16/Balsn-CTF-2019-Bank/) is an example where `callback` function is included in `SafeBox` struct, whereas it says 8 bytes storage for this function type.And how the 8 bytes are made of?
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: I don't think you can store `function` types in structs. It would be helpful if you added a code snippet to explain what you want to do.

Comment: Have added @PaulRazvanBerg

Comment: I think I've found a useful reference [here](https://github.com/ethereum/solidity/issues/13603), but it doesn't explain how the 8 bytes for internal function are made up in details.

Answer (score 0):

The `callback` function inside the struct will only be 8 bytes, I got the storage layout for the `SafeBox` struct members and it is:

```
"members": [
                  {
                    "label": "done",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "slot": "0",
                    "type": "t_bool"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "callback",
                    "offset": 1,
                    "slot": "0",
                    "type": "t_function_internal_nonpayable(t_uint256,t_bytes12)returns()"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "hash",
                    "offset": 9,
                    "slot": "0",
                    "type": "t_bytes12"
                  },
                  {
                    "label": "value",
                    "offset": 0,
                    "slot": "1",
                    "type": "t_uint256"
                  }
                ],
```

As you can see it fits with the other variables inside the slot 0, if it were 32 bytes it would be on a different slot. Also the storage layout print the number of bytes of the types and it confirms is just 8 bytes:

```
              "t_function_internal_nonpayable(t_uint256,t_bytes12)returns()": {
                "encoding": "inplace",
                "label": "function (uint256,bytes12)",
                "numberOfBytes": "8"
              }
```

Comment: Thanks! But do you know how the 8 bytes are made of?